# Can't get jquery resize function to work properly

Tags: jquery, html, class, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create a function that checks the browser window width and applies or removes classes depending on what the width is. However, I either can't seem to remove one of the classes and can't get the function based on the classes to work either.

**The concept is:**
On window resize, IF the window width exceeds 480px to have the class "deskop" applied to the figure ".grid-block", and the class "mobile" removed. ELSE, if the window width goes below 481px to have the class "desktop" removed and "mobile" applied.
Then, if a ".grid-block" has the class "desktop", allow this mousover effect to take place. If the figure has the class "mobile", prevent the mouseover.

**My problems are:**
I couldn't get the class applying/removing resize function to fire properly, so I borrowed and revised some code I found and it ended up looking like this...

```
$(window).load(function() {
  (function($) {
    var $window = $(window),
    $block = $('.grid-block');

    function resize() {
      if ($window.width() < 481) {
        return $block.addClass('mobile');
      }
      $block.removeClass('mobile');
      if ($window.width() > 480) {
        return $block.addClass('desktop');
      }
      $block.removeClass('desktop');
    }
    $window
    .resize(resize)
    .trigger('resize')
  })(jQuery);
});
```

This function assigns the mobile class properly, but it always keeps the desktop class. So be it- I thought- so I revised the function to omit using the desktop class and to have my functions based entirely on the figure element having the mobile class or not, like so...

```
if (!$('.grid-block').hasClass("mobile")) {
  $('.grid-block').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find("figcaption").removeClass("testopacity");
  });
  $('.grid-block').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find("figcaption").addClass("testopacity");
  });
}
```

Instead of checking to see if the ".grid-block" figure has the "mobile" class applied, it just goes ahead with the mouseover function no matter what the browser window width is.

What is wrong with my functions? Why doesn't the first one remove the desktop class, and why doesn't the second one check for the mobile class before performing it's function?

Comment: Can you create a codepen or jsfiddle to show us the  problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try your first resize function with minor update. It appears that you never reach the code at this line **$block.removeClass('desktop');** as you return before that! So move that line as shown below and try:

```
if ($window.width() < 481) {
  $block.removeClass('desktop');
  return $block.addClass('mobile');
}
```